# JApplet NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener, japplet

I programmed a GUI to display the provinces and territories of Canada. It all seemed to work well, but every time I compiled the program, I'm having an issue with `NullPointerException`, but not when I compile, only when I try to open the web browser. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;   // the "basic" awt functionality
import javax.swing.*;   // java's awesome swing functionality
import java.awt.event.*;   // necessary for event listeners

public class ProvincesofCanada extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    //components
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField provinceCapital;
    private JTextField provincePopulation;
    private JTextField provinceConfederation;
    private JComboBox provinceNameList;

    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel motto;
    private JLabel provinceMotto;
    private JLabel provinceName;

    private ImageIcon provinceFlag;
    private ImageIcon provinceMap;
    private JLabel flagLabel;
    private JLabel mapLabel;

    private JLabel spacer;

    //constants for window size
    //private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 257;
    //private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 535;

    public ProvincesofCanada(){

        //Issue the title of the program
        //setTitle("Provinces and Territories of Canada");

        //Specify what happens when the close button is pressed
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Build the panel that contains the other components
        buildPanel();

        //Add the panel to the content pane
        add(panel);

        //Set the size and display the window
        //setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        //setVisible(true);

    }

    public void buildPanel(){

        //Choose a Province prompt
        JLabel chooseAProvince = new JLabel("Choose a Province");

        String[] provinces = {"","Alberta","British Columbia","Manitoba",
        "New Brunswick", "Newfoundland and Labrador","Northwest Territories",
        "Nova Scotia","Nunavut","Ontario","Prince Edward Island","Quebec","Saskatchewan","Yukon Territory"};
        provinceNameList = new JComboBox(provinces);

        //ComboBox Listener
        provinceNameList.addActionListener(this);

        //Province Name 
        provinceName = new JLabel();
        provinceName.setText("<html>Welcome to Canada<br>Bienvenue au Canada</html>");

        //Province Motto    
        provinceMotto = new JLabel("");

        Label lb1 = new Label();

        // create a flag image icon
        java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/canadaflag.png");
        flagLabel = new JLabel();
        flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));

        // create a map image icon
        provinceMap = new ImageIcon("images/canadamap.png");
        mapLabel = new JLabel();
        mapLabel.setIcon(provinceMap);

        //Province Data 
        JLabel provinceCapitalLabel = new JLabel("Capital: ");
        JLabel provincePopulationLabel = new JLabel("Population: ");
        JLabel provinceConfederationLabel = new JLabel("Confederation: ");

        // Create text fields
        provinceCapital = new JTextField(10);
        provinceCapital.setText("Ottawa");
        provinceCapital.setEditable(false);

        provincePopulation = new JTextField(10);
        provincePopulation.setText("33,476,688");
        provincePopulation.setEditable(false);

        provinceConfederation = new JTextField(6);
        provinceConfederation.setText("1867");
        provinceConfederation.setEditable(false);

        //Create new line
        JLabel newLine = new JLabel(" ");

        //create new instance of JPanel called panel        
        panel = new JPanel();

        //add components to panel
        panel.add(chooseAProvince);
        panel.add(provinceNameList);
        panel.add(provinceName);
        panel.add(provinceMotto);
        panel.add(flagLabel);
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(mapLabel);
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(provinceCapitalLabel);
        panel.add(provinceCapital);
        panel.add(spacer = new JLabel(" "),"span, grow");
        panel.add(provincePopulationLabel);
        panel.add(provincePopulation);
        panel.add(provinceConfederationLabel);
        panel.add(provinceConfederation);       
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String provinceChoice = String.valueOf(provinceNameList.getSelectedItem()); 

        if (provinceChoice == "Alberta"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Fortis et liber\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/abflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/abmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Edmonton");
            provincePopulation.setText("3,645,257");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1905");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "British Columbia"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Splendor sine occasu\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/bcflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/bcmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Victoria");
            provincePopulation.setText("4,400,057");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1871");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Manitoba"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Gloriosus ey Liber\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/mbflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/mbmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Winnipeg");
            provincePopulation.setText("1,208,268");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1870");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "New Brunswick"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Spem Reduxit\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nbflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nbmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Fredericton");
            provincePopulation.setText("751,171");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1867");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Newfoundland and Labrador"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Quaerite Prime Regnum Dei\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nlflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nlmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("St. John's");
            provincePopulation.setText("514,536");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1949");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Northwest Territories"){

            provinceName.setText(provinceChoice);
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/ntflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/ntmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Yellowknife");
            provincePopulation.setText("41,462");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1870");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Nova Scotia"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Munit Haec ey Altera Vincit\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nsflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nsmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Halifax");
            provincePopulation.setText("921,727");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1867");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Nunavut"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Nunavut Sanginivut\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/nuflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/numap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Iqaluit");
            provincePopulation.setText("31,906");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1999");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Ontario"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Ut Incepit Fidelis Sic Permanet\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/onflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/onmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Toronto");
            provincePopulation.setText("12,851,821");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1867");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Prince Edward Island"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Parva Sub Ingenti\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/peflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/pemap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Charlottetown");
            provincePopulation.setText("140,204");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1873");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Quebec"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Je me souviens\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/qbflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/qbmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Quebec City");
            provincePopulation.setText("7,903,001");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1867");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Saskatchewan"){

            provinceName.setText("<html><center>" + provinceChoice + "<br>\"Multibus E Gentibus Vires\"</center></html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/skflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/skmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Regina");
            provincePopulation.setText("1,033,381");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1905");

        } else if (provinceChoice == "Yukon Territory"){

            provinceName.setText(provinceChoice);
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/ytflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/ytmap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Whitehorse");
            provincePopulation.setText("33,897");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1898");

        } else{
            provinceName.setText("<html>Welcome to Canada<br>/Bienvenue au Canada</html>");
            provinceMotto.setText("");
            java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/canadaflag.png");
            flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag));
            java.net.URL provinceMap = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/canadamap.png");
            mapLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceMap));
            provinceCapital.setText("Ottawa");
            provincePopulation.setText("33,476,688");
            provinceConfederation.setText("1867");

        }
    }

    // //main method
//  public static void main(String[] args){
//      ProvincesofCanada poc = new ProvincesofCanada();
//  }

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Provinces and Territories of Canada</title>
    </head>
    <body></br></br>
        <center><applet code ="ProvincesofCanada.class" width="257" height="535"></center>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: You are only receiving it at runtime because exceptions are runtime errors and not compile errors.

Comment: Just for info, exceptions don't occur at compile time, they occur at runtime only.

Comment: You also need to use `equals()` instead of `==` to compare your strings (at least, the NPE can not occur in any of the `if()` blocks)

Comment: This, `provinceMap = new ImageIcon("images/canadamap.png");` looks suspicious.  I don't think you understand how resources are managed by applets

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE because `provinceFlag` is null at following line:

```
// create a flag image icon
    java.net.URL provinceFlag = ProvincesofCanada.class.getResource("images/canadaflag.png");

    System.out.println(provinceFlag);//null

    flagLabel = new JLabel();
    flagLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(provinceFlag)); // Null Pointer Exception
```

[Class#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) returns null if no resource with this name is found.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely place would be getting the image resources. `getResource(...)` yields null when not found. The path names must be case-sensitive. If the class has a package (recommended), the path should have been "/images/...".

---

***Correction:***

```
provinceMap = new ImageIcon("images/canadamap.png");
```

This seems the culprit. Use the getResource here too. This is interpreted as file path.